# Set slash directory in git bash

Tags: linux, windows, git, bash, mingw32

I have msysgit installed in my PC. I want to change the path of `/` using environment variables. Currently it is pointing to `c:\program files\git`. How can I change this?

**Note:** I am able to change path of `~` directory using `HOME` environment variable. I am looking for similar solution for this.

Comment: @Kent http://msysgit.github.io/

Comment: Oh, thx!  a little git shell on win. I have seen the screen on my win-colleagues' monitors, but I thought they installed cygwin. I was wrong, that is the thing!

Comment: How did you change the HOME ?

Comment: @ꜱᴀᴍᴏᴛʜ `HOME=/d/xyx/`. You can add it to Windows environment variables or `git/etc/profile`

Comment: Why do you want to change this?  The Unix filesystem semantics are important; if `/usr/bin` suddenly disappeared, this would be very bad indeed.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I am on windows using Mingw32 shipped with git installer. I don't think there will any harm in this.

Answer (score 0):

The software package that installs git `bash` is similar to Cygwin (I think it may be based on Cygwin, but I'm not sure of that). It's designed to emulate a UNIX-like environment under Windows.

As far as I know, the location of the `/` directory (referred to as the *root directory*) is fixed when you install the software. If you want `/` to refer to a different location in the Windows filesystem, you'll need to reinstall the software and, if possible, specify a different location. It can't be changed by setting an environment variable.

What exactly are you trying to do? There may be some way to accomplish your goal other than changing the location of `/`.